# Creating tables with descriptive statistics in R

Tags: r, r-markdown

I would like some help on creating formatted tables in R - whether it's just using the normal IDE or R Markdown. There are two main things that I'd like to do:

- Present the descriptive statistics (Mean, Median, Min, Max) by group based on different columns
- Present the descriptive statistic based on the total sample (ungrouped data)

Sample data:

```
   df <- data.frame(Gender = c("F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M"),
                 Young = c("Y", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "N"),
                 Age = c("14", "25", "13", "24", "14", "25", "13", "24", "10", "26"),
                 Location = c("Suburb", "Rural", "Suburb", "Rural","Suburb", "Rural","Suburb", "Rural","Suburb", "Rural"))
```

Expected results

| Variable | Mean | Median | Max | Min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Gender** |  |  |  |  |
| Female |  |  |  |  |
| Male |  |  |  |  |
| **Location** |  |  |  |  |
| Suburb |  |  |  |  |
| Rural |  |  |  |  |
| **TOTAL** |  |  |  |  |

Is there a way to do this in R?

Comment: Your sample data seems to be missing the *data*. Where are the numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get all the information that you need by getting the data in long format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Age) %>%
  group_by(name, value) %>%
  summarise(min_age = min(Age), 
            max_age = max(Age), 
            median_age = median(Age), 
            mean_age = mean(Age))

#  name     value  min_age max_age median_age mean_age
#  <chr>    <chr>    <int>   <int>      <int>    <dbl>
#1 Gender   F           13      24         14     17  
#2 Gender   M           10      26         24     19.6
#3 Location Rural       24      26         25     24.8
#4 Location Suburb      10      14         13     12.8
#5 Young    N           24      26         25     24.8
#6 Young    Y           10      14         13     12.8
```

Comment: Hi,

Sorry to bring this up but I would like to avoid a repost. Is there any way to format the table as per OP's example? More specifically, to have one row with just the name and then the subsequent rows to have the Value and the descriptives.

Answer (score 1):

Similar answer using data.table:

```
> library(data.table)
> df <- data.frame(Gender = c("F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M"),
+                  Young = c("Y", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "N"),
+                  Age = c("14", "25", "13", "24", "14", "25", "13", "24", 
+                          "10", "26"),
+                  Location = c("Suburb", "Rural", "Suburb", 
+                               "Rural","Suburb", "Rural","Suburb", 
+                               "Rural","Suburb", "Rural"))
> setDT(df)                        # make it a data.table    
> df[,Age:=as.integer(Age)]        # correct age column   
> df[,.(mean=mean(Age), median=median(Age), max=max(Age), min=min(Age)),
+     by=.(Gender,Location)]   
   Gender Location    mean median max min
1:      F   Suburb 13.5000   13.5  14  13
2:      M    Rural 25.0000   25.0  26  24
3:      M   Suburb 12.3333   13.0  14  10
4:      F    Rural 24.0000   24.0  24  24
>
```

Or if we want to stratify by one variable at a time:

```
> df[,.(mean=mean(Age), median=median(Age), max=max(Age),min=min(Age)), 
+    by=.(Gender)]
   Gender    mean median max min
1:      F 17.0000     14  24  13
2:      M 19.5714     24  26  10
> df[,.(mean=mean(Age), median=median(Age), max=max(Age), min=min(Age)), 
+    by=.(Location)]
   Location mean median max min
1:   Suburb 12.8     13  14  10
2:    Rural 24.8     25  26  24
>
```

And inspired by Ronak's nice answer, the same as a data.table one-liner:

```
> melt(df, id.vars="Age")[, .(mean=mean(Age), 
+                             median=median(Age), 
+                             min=min(Age), 
+                             max=max(Age)), by=.(variable,value)]
   variable  value    mean median min max
1:   Gender      F 17.0000     14  13  24
2:   Gender      M 19.5714     24  10  26
3:    Young      Y 12.8000     13  10  14
4:    Young      N 24.8000     25  24  26
5: Location Suburb 12.8000     13  10  14
6: Location  Rural 24.8000     25  24  26
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Several packages have wrapped functions for this. I usually use `describe` from {psych} package.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(Gender = c("F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M"),
                 Young = c("Y", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "N"),
                 Age = c("14", "25", "13", "24", "14", "25", "13", "24", "10", "26"),
                 Location = c("Suburb", "Rural", "Suburb", "Rural","Suburb", "Rural","Suburb", "Rural","Suburb", "Rural"))

df_summary <- psych::describe(df)

df_summary

         vars  n mean   sd median trimmed  mad min max range  skew kurtosis   se
Gender*      1 10  1.7 0.48    2.0    1.75 0.00   1   2     1 -0.75    -1.57 0.15
Young*       2 10  1.5 0.53    1.5    1.50 0.74   1   2     1  0.00    -2.19 0.17
Age*         3 10  3.5 1.58    3.5    3.50 2.22   1   6     5  0.00    -1.42 0.50
Location*    4 10  1.5 0.53    1.5    1.50 0.74   1   2     1  0.00    -2.19 0.17
```

You can then use `dplyr` to do whatever you want.

```
df_summary %>% select(mean, median, max, min)
```

Comment: But it doesn't describe `Age` conditional on the values of `Gender`, `Young` or `Location`.  So this is different.

Comment: They also have a function `describeBy`

Comment: Good to know. How about adding that as an edit to your answer, illustrating how it can be used?  `psych` is a local-across-town package so I've long been a fan.